# small business 10 workstation network mess

Tags: windows, workstation-management

Fellow friends,

I am in a dire need for help.
I have gotten myself in a situation where I am expected to take care of small business computer network.
Little background: I'm in sales/marketing sector in company, and because I'm on help desk-level of computer knowledge, the boss thinks a can manage the whole setup.

Oh my God.
The setup is a mess.
There are 10 computers, one ADSL commercial modem, two 5 port switches. All computers are Windows XP workstation with critical business information on all of them, no antivirus, no updates. And the one workstation is named "server".

What can I do to make a setup that will work with stability, to automate cleanup/patch jobs, to understand what is failing and make my life livable.
How to plan for remote work, and how to add a layer of security?

Please advise

Comment: The general consensus is, _find a new job immediately_, in your _desired_ line of work.

Comment: I'm a freelance IT consultant and I may be able to help. Feel free to contact me at the email address in my profile if you're interested.

Comment: Yup, hire a consultant ASAP.  You can get the worst of your environment fixed and establish a solid foundation, rather than the timebomb you have now, and it'd be pretty cheap... sounds like it would be something you could get sorted out in a couple weeks or so with a good consultant.